# How can I change the look of the "Create new table" window in IntelliJ

Tags: database, intellij-idea

I am just starting to learn about databases using MariaDB and IntelliJ. The videos I have are using a different style of window, when you create a table and this is driving up the wall as the way it is on my computer is completely different and I can't manage to do what I want.

[How it looks on my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUKiA.png)

[How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFb0h.png)

I've gone through all the settings I could think of, but didn't manage to find where to change it. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a recent change, DataGrip (Database plugin in IntelliJ IDEA) introduced a new UI for Modify pop-ups: https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2022/08/23/datagrip-2022-2-2-improves-the-modify-object-ui/.

You can still use an old one by selecting *New | Table (Old UI)* in *Database* tool window.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was going crazy. I managed to do what I wanted with the new version, but it took me 3 times as long as it should have to figure out how to do it. And it was driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is looking,
this feature was removed from datagrip in the latest update.
I went and downloaded an older version as the new create table UI makes datagrip unplayable.

https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/download/other.html